# Intellij/Scalatest failing to start tests

Tags: intellij-idea, scalatest, playspec

I am running my Playspec tests but I keep getting error that 60 of the tests failed to start. What is surprising is the nesting of test cases.

Sorry, I don't have more information at the moment. What does the nested testcase list (lower left corner) in the picture mean? Are these test running in parallel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that each test was starting its own instance of database. After a point in time, the system gets overwhelmed.